# Different names in paired-end sequence files

Tags: dna-sequencing

I am aligning paired end sequence reads using `bwa mem` and I get an error saying that `paired reads have different names: "M01814:86:000000000-A6MU9:1:1101:15545:1335", "M01814:86:000000000-A6MU9:1:1101:16059:1338"` So it looks like the locations for some of the reads don't quite match up. Is there a way to ignore these reads? Or to use them but not treat them as pairs?

Comment: are those Illumina reads?

Comment: Yes from the MiSeq

Comment: Ok, just wanted to confirm. Will look into it.

Comment: Do you have equal number of reads in your files (I assume you have separate files for the two ends).

Comment: Yep exact same number in each file.

Comment: According to this document : http://support.illumina.com/help/SequencingAnalysisWorkflow/Content/Vault/Informatics/Sequencing_Analysis/CASAVA/swSEQ_mCA_FASTQFiles.htm the position of your reads on the sequencing tile don't match, but I think you've figured that out if i'm not mistaken by *" it looks like the locations for some of the reads don't quite match up"* You could delete these reads to solve the problem. I have no other suggestion without knowing more of your setup.

Comment: Yeah I did already figure that out. And deleting the reads would be less than ideal, but may be the route I need to go. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: I assumed that you've figured this, but wanted to make sure, so that I don't make mistakes while trying to help you. I found some links that might help you resync your files : https://www.biostars.org/p/6925/#6928
 https://www.biostars.org/p/12576/#12578 http://seqanswers.com/forums/showpost.php?p=141460&postcount=45
originally from here:http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=46538

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24851/discussion-between-nandor-poka-and-the-nightman).

Comment: Paired reads do not have different headers. Most likely these are singletons. You can provide an option to your aligner to not align singletons.

Comment: @TheNightman How many singletons do you have? Just parse and see.

Comment: I'm not sure how to see how many singletons I have. Do you know how to do this?